# Layout preview not showing in every layout - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, preview

At first, initializing took a long time and after initializing, the preview did not work. Every layout got the same problem. What should I do to solve this problem?
I already tried Invalidating Caches, Update Android version, rebuild & clean project, changing the theme.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What Android Studio version are you using? I had a similar problem and updated to Iguana 2023.2.1 version (beta) with JetBrains Toolbox, and it's fixed now.